# How does uint types conversion works?

Tags: solidity, overflow

It seems (seemed) intuitive to me that there is no need to convert lower uints (e.g. `uint8`) to higher ones (`uint256`) within a formula. As I understood from the solidity docs it should be done automatically.

Am I wrong? Why am I getting "premature" overflows in the functions below?

This function works well until `numSold` is lower or equal to 15999. After that there is overflow.

```
function debugPower (uint16 numSold) public constant returns (uint) {
    return uint(2 ** (numSold/1000));
}
```

This function works well until `numSold` is lower or equal to 6999. Then overflow.

```
function debugPrice (uint8 x1, uint8 y1, uint16 numSold) private returns (uint80) {
    return uint80(1 finney * (2 ** (numSold/1000))); 
}
```

The same as above setting_delay never even close to `uint32`, `currentLevel` never close to `uint16` and the final result never close to `uint`.

```
function debugActivationTime (uint32 setting_delay, uint16 currentLevel) public constant returns (uint32) {
    return uint32(now + ((2**(currentLevel-1)) * setting_delay)); 
}
```

Comment: waiting for the answer i had the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that this expression:

```
return uint(2 ** (numSold/1000));
```

first evaluates `2 ** (numSold/1000)`, and deduces the resulting type from the type of `numSold`. So the truncation is happening before the value can ever be cast. The solution is to cast `numSold` to a `uint` *first*.

i.e.

```
return 2 ** uint(numSold/1000);
```